# How to run a java code in my compiler

Tags: java, javac

Whats the difference between java and javac?

I have a problem when running this code?

```
Class A{
public static void main(String...a){
System.out.println();    
}
}
```

how to run in cmd

Comment: what/where is `S.O.P()` ?

Comment: Print your error stack trace.

Comment: @Sanjeev - system out println. sop for the lazy :)

Comment: That is not valid Java code.

Comment: `javac`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html and `java`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: `S.O.P()` requires a parameter to P. Unless you mean `S.O.(P)` in which case you should use a more [precise search query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=P).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto your souce codes path locaton from the cmd.
then  `javac A.java`

```
Java A
```

the file have to be named as A .Java first

Answer (score 2):

`javac` - is for compiling a Java file. It generates a .class file from the class.

example-

```
javac test.java
```

`java` - is to run a generated class file

example-

```
java test
```

Answer (score 1):

`javac` does the compiling for you and `java` is for running up the compiled .class file(i.e running the `bytecode`)

[image]

see this

[image]

- First line is  for `moving to the directory where your .java file`(in this case it is my desktop)
- Second is to `compile the java code`(my .java file is named as MyClass.java)
- Third is for `running the compiled .class file`